# bash script for activeDirectory join; facing issues using expect to bypass password entry

Tags: bash, scripting, rhel, expect, active-directory

Will preface here stating that this is **poor practice** but I have been requested anyway to store the svc-account credential within the script which will live in vRA for VM template.. not my choice, but due to use case, there cannot be user input. I am currently trying to use expect to send the svc account password. I see the prompt, and the script completes without error, but does not join the domain.. I am not sure if it is sending the credentials set as variable...

```bash
#!/bin/sh

yum -y install sssd realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common samba-common-tools krb5-workstation openldap-clients python3-policycoreutils expect

OU="OU=Computers,OU=Object Staging, DC=test,DC=acme,DC=com"

echo "OU selected is: $OU "

export OU

expect -c '

set OU "Computers,OU=Object Staging, DC=test,DC=acme,DC=com"

set PASS bugsBunny

spawn sudo realm join --user=svc-domainJoin --computer-ou="\$OU" test.acme.com ;

expect "Password for svc-domainJoin:"; send {"$PASS"\r\"; interact } ;
'
realm list
```

additionally, I am not seeing the output of realm list after; when I ran this script without expect (and user input); this cmd did execute

Comment: The quoting for the  `send` command is wrong. Try `send "$PASS\r"; interact`

Comment: Thank you! that did work and appreciate your response as I'm learning through this. The other answer did illuminate that I do not need expect here

Comment: @onceIHadASoul94 you seem to be happy with the answer offered below. Please consider accepting it with the ✔ mark, as that's how we say "thank you" here on the StackExchange sites

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `expect`. These commands accept directly from STDIN the password:

```
OU="Computers,OU=Object Staging, DC=test,DC=acme,DC=com"
PASS=bugsBunny
printf "%s\n" "$PASS" |sudo realm join --user=svc-domainJoin --computer-ou="\$OU" test.acme.com
```

And probably you do not need this backslash before `OU`

```
printf "%s\n" "$PASS" |sudo realm join --user=svc-domainJoin --computer-ou="$OU" test.acme.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @onceIHadASoul94, if you are happy with my answer and in reasonable time you do not like any other answer feel free to accept mine

Comment: @roaima, probably its a error (the backslash)